# Integrating to find net pressure and force on a sphere by a fluid

Tags: pressure, integration, fluid-statics

How would I go about solving for the net force on a sphere exerted by air pressure as a result of pressure being dependent only on the vertical position of the ball? When the sphere it is placed in a funnel shape and air is blown out, the ball rises because there is less area above the ball, so higher velocity and lower pressure, and the opposite happens below, meaning a difference in pressure leads to an upwards force. I think you have to take the $y$-component of the force on each ring of the sphere using $F = \frac{P}{A}$, but when I attempt to integrate it becomes extremely messy. Does anyone know how to effectively solve this?

Comment: Can you provide the "messy" math you've done so we can know exactly where you got it wrong.

Comment: I think its not $F = \dfrac{P}{A}$, it's $F = PA$.